# Dismiss UIImagePickerController is not working in IOS 7

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have tried every variation of dismissing a UIImagePickerController without any luck. What am I doing wrong.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
[picker.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
imageview.image = image;


}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{

   [picker.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

I don't know where I doing wrong I'm ruining this on iOS 7. Can anyone suggest me what is right way to do it ?

Comment: put code of present `UIImagePickerController`.. becoz dismiss is also depend upon present so..

Comment: you can vote up my answer too

Comment: sorry bro for up vote i need 15 reputation but i have only 7 sorry ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Here self is the UIImagePickerController

Answer (score 2):

put `self` to current `UIImagePickerController`

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```